# Add new series to the top of a highcharts stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, stacked

I'm trying to control the order in which new (after first render) series are added to a stacked column chart in Highcharts. Right now, if you simply use addSeries, the newly added series is added to the bottom of the stack. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'base',
        data: [10, 20, 30]
    }, {
        name: 'sec',
        data: [30, 20, 10]
    }]
});

var i = 0;
$('#add').on('click', function (e) {
    chart.addSeries({
        data: [32, 43, 42],
        name: ++i,
        index: 0 //??????
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/6bCBf/

Any one can think of a way to reverse/control where Highcharts inserts the new series?

I've tried setting the index of the new series to 0, but that does nothing. Setting it to -1 adds the new series to the bottom of the array, but then that 'stacking' does not work properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set index and zIndex to keep order between layers, then add serie with appropriate parameters.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6bCBf/5/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
         }
     },    

    series: [
        {
            name: 'base',
            data: [10, 20, 30],
            index:2,
            zIndex:10
        },
        {
            name: 'sec',
            data: [30, 20, 10],
            index:1,
            zIndex:9
        }
    ]
},function(chart){



    $('#add').on('click', function (e) {

        chart.addSeries({
            data: [32, 43, 42],
            index: 0,
            zIndex:1
        });
    });


});
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!, its strange that you have to tweak both things to simply reverse the orders...

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts also supports a [`yAxis.reversedStacks`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.reversedStacks) property which, if set to `false`, will reverse the order of the stacking data points. In the OP's JSFiddle, the first series, "base", appeared on the top of the chart, while the second series, "sec", appeared below it. Setting `reversedStacks: false` as in [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/em86b4dv/) reverses that order, and the new series appears on the top of the stack instead of the bottom.